# in bamboo: how to download latest _stable_ artifact?

Tags: bamboo

[This page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Viewing+a+build%27s+artifacts) says that I can go straight to downloading that lastest artifact of a plan by navigating to `http://server/bamboo/browse/MYBUILD/latest/artifact/logs/sample-log.log`, but is there a way I can directly ask for the artifact of the latest build **which succeeded**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can replace the "latest" in the url with "latestSuccessful" and that will return the most recent execution of that plan that was successful.